# On the connection between SSE and absolute deviation from the centroids

Tags: clustering, standard-deviation, sums-of-squares

Is there any connection between sum of squared error SSE and the absolute deviation from the centroids after clustering.

More formally, I have clustered $T=\{x_i\}, i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and the results are $c$ clusters: $T^C=\{C_j\}, j\in\{1,\ldots,c\}$ (As a side note, I appreciate your comments on the notations). All records $x_i$ are assigned to clusters $G_j$ with the centroids $C_j=MEAN(x_i), x_i\in G_j$, so SSE is calculated as:

$\sum\limits_{\underset{x_i\in G_j}{i=1}}^{n}(x_i-C_j)^2$

I am seeking a way to calculate/estimate the following:

$\sum\limits_{\underset{x_i\in G_j}{i=1}}^{n}|x_i-C_j|$

However, I am not sure whether there is such a connection  or not.

My algorithm is something similar to K-means and Euclidean distances are used.

Thanks

Comment: Which clustering algorithm did you used (from your words it looks like a k-means)? Which distance did you used (it looks like euclidean distance on numeric variables)?

Comment: Yes, I edited the question.

Comment: I did not understand it. What prevents you from computing the sum of absolute deviations? Is there some quantity you don't know for that?

Answer (score 1):

If you use k-medians instead of k-means, you can use absolute deviations.

It's a pretty straightforward adaption of the algorithm (just use the median in each dimension instead of the mean) and optimizes $L_1$ norms.

Arithmetic mean and quadratic mean are obviously closely related, and yield similar values on nicely behaved data. Then $\sqrt{\frac{1}{nd}SSE}\approx \frac{1}{nd} SAE$. If your data is not nicely behaved, then they will be more different.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you please let me know why you said $\sqrt{\frac{1}{nd}SSE}$ and not $\frac{1}{nd}\sqrt{SSE}$. What is more formal meaning of nicely behaved data?

Comment: It is unclear whether $SSE$ and/or $SAE$ in your formula is about the mean (centroid) or about the geometric median. And what is "nicely behaved". Also, it seems to me that the OP was about centroids only...

Comment: @remo: Because quadratic mean (RMS) is the square root of the average squared value; not the other way round. On your lucky day (="nicely behaved data") quadratic mean and arithmetic mean do not make much of a difference.